# MySQL database with ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net, mysql

I want to use MySql database with ASP .NET application using DBLINQ.
I am following the link -

http://www.primaryobjects.com/CMS/Article100.aspx

But, I am not able to connect MySQL file with ASP .NET application.

What are exact steps to attach MySql file with .NET application?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try different connection string from [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql)

Answer (score 0):

If you have not done this before, I would check first if the user can connect to mysql out of the .NET application with a GUI admin (SQLYog for example - but not phpMyAdmin as it connects as localhost on the server and your app not) from the same machine the application runs. You need the same user in mysql with the right host (or %) if mysql server is not running on the same machine. The user needs also at least SELECT right on the database you will use.

Answer (score 0):

Database connections can be very tricky.

Here's a checklist for you:

- Connection String

  - Is your connection String in the correct format?
  - Is the username correct?
  - Is the password correct?
  - Is the database correct? (This is what most people forget)
- Db File

  - Is the path to the file correct. (That's part of the connection string)
  - Does your application have the rights to open files in this path. (Can be dangerous if path is in a Network Drive or on C:/Users or C:/Program Files.
  - Does your user have the rights?

Answer (score 0):

If you have already installed MySQL software on Windows,
 then you need to add
[image]

or you need to install mysql connector for .NET. [link](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/8.0.html)

Then connect to the project asp net  MySql.Date
[image] 
And now you can use MySqlConnection